# Accents with lmodern fonts on XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, accents

After loading the `lmroman10-regular` font in XeTeX, I can't access accents in TeX' good old ways: `\'`  `\"` `\c` etc. I would need to write `Erd\H os` since because I don't have the appropriate "o" on my keyboard.

Example:

```
Before: é, \'e

\font\tenrm="[lmroman10-regular.otf]:mapping=tex-text"
\tenrm

After: é, \'e

\bye
```

Output:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to redefine the macros, because the accents are in different places.

Comment: But why the hell do you want the bad old way? It can break hyphenation, and makes your source unreadable.

Comment: @Bernard because I need to write Erd\H os and I don't have the right character on my keyboard :). (I go edit my question to make this clearer)

Comment: I don't understand: I have no problem to obtain Erdős from Erd\H{o}s with XeLaTeX. But wouldn't it be simpler to configure your editor to obtain ő and Ő with a shortcut?

Comment: @Bernard my problem is that, with XeTeX (maybe it's done differently in XeLaTeX), when I load the lmroman10-regular font, the accent-like commands don't work anymore. Try to compile my snippet (it's a full XeTeX file, no need for preamble or `\end{document}`) with XeTeX and you'll see that, in the output, `\'e` doesn't produce é but e.

Comment: @Bernard: you are probably loading xunicode (through fontspec) which set up all this definitions. And such commands don't disturb hyphenation when they point to the same char as the direct input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use combining characters, instead. Unfortunately, Latin Modern does not fully implement them; for instance, there's no combining cedilla, so with the code below you'd get only characters with cedilla which exist in the font.

```
Before: 
\c{e}
\`{e} \'{e}
\v{e} \u{e}
\={e} \^{e}
\.{e} \H{e}
\~{e} \"{e}

\font\tenrm="[lmroman10-regular.otf]:mapping=tex-text"
\tenrm

\def\`#1{#1^^^^0300} \def\'#1{#1^^^^0301}
\def\v#1{#1^^^^030c} \def\u#1{#1^^^^0306}
\def\=#1{#1^^^^0304} \def\^#1{#1^^^^0302}
\def\.#1{#1^^^^0307} \def\H#1{#1^^^^030b}
\def\~#1{#1^^^^0303} \def\"#1{#1^^^^0308}
\def\c#1{#1^^^^0327}

After:
\c{c}
\`{e} \'{e}
\v{e} \u{e}
\={e} \^{e}
\.{e} \H{e}
\~{e} \"{e}

\bye
```

Why is this better than using `\accent`? Because the characters are *themselves*, not built-up boxes and kern combinations.

[image]

If you use `cmunrm.otf` (CMU Serif) that has the combining cedilla, you'd get also `\c{e}` (as a pair `e`+`combining cedilla`).

Note that combining characters go after the character they modify. If a combinations such as `e`+`combining acute` is defined by Unicode, the *real* U+00E8 (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE) would result in the PDF file, available for copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

By copying the definitions at page 356 of the TeXbook but changing the character codes, this fixes it:

```
Before: 
\c{e}
\`{e} \'{e}
\v{e} \u{e}
\={e} \^{e}
\.{e} \H{e}
\~{e} \"{e}

\font\tenrm="[lmroman10-regular.otf]:mapping=tex-text"
\tenrm
\def\`#1{{\accent768 #1}} \def\'#1{{\accent180 #1}}
\def\v#1{{\accent711 #1}} \def\u#1{{\accent728 #1}}
\def\=#1{{\accent175 #1}} \def\^#1{{\accent710 #1}}
\def\.#1{{\accent729 #1}} \def\H#1{{\accent733 #1}}
\def\~#1{{\accent732 #1}} \def\"#1{{\accent168 #1}}
\def\c#1{{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\ifdim\ht0=1ex \accent184 #1%
\else\ooalign{\unhbox0\crcr\hidewidth\char184\hidewidth}\fi}}

After:
\c{e}
\`{e} \'{e}
\v{e} \u{e}
\={e} \^{e}
\.{e} \H{e}
\~{e} \"{e}

\bye
```

Output:
[image]